# R: Extracting non-duplicated values from vector (not keeping one value for duplicates)

Tags: r

I would like to keep the non-duplicated values from a vector, but without retaining one element from duplicated values. unique() does not work for this. Neither would duplicated().

For example:

```
> test <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9)
> unique(test)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Whereas I would like the result to be: 2,3,5,7,8

Any ideas on how to approach this? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ave` to count the `length` of sub-groups divided by unique values in `test` and retain only the ones whose length is 1 (the ones that have no duplicates)

```
test[ave(test, test, FUN = length) == 1]
#[1] 2 3 5 7 8
```

If `test` is comprised of characters, use `seq_along` as first argument of ave

```
test[ave(seq_along(test), test, FUN = length) == 1]
```

Comment: Is it possible that this does not work on character vectors?

Comment: No need for anonymous functions here

Comment: Ok now you're graduated : )

Answer (score 11):

We can use `duplicated`

```
test[!(duplicated(test)|duplicated(test, fromLast=TRUE))]
#[1] 2 3 5 7 8
```

Comment: imo this should have received the tick - much better to work with vectors where possible, rather than splitting and looping